# hosting a wordpress site locally to my team

Tags: localhost, hosting

I am trying to host a wordpress blog to my team in my company (max 30 people). I would add/edit my content in admin mode and the team who are in same network are supposed to see the content whenever they type the url. My current URL is
*myip/wordpressfoldername* — This gives me admin view of the site. I can edit the contents and settings
*localhost/wordpressfoldername* –Thisalso gives me same as above.Except that the landing page doesnt have site customisation options . Rest remains the same

How to proceed to host this site so that my team mates can do a read only and I can do edit/add/delete
Now When I type http://myip/wordpressfoldername from any other computer .I am getting ‘You don’t have permission to access / on this server.’ error.

Comment: You IP keeps on changing. So please check the latest IP.

Comment: my machine IP? no

Comment: you may have .htaccess access file and that is blocking other person with different IP. Please check the .htaccess file

Comment: .htaccess file inside www folder

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: .htaccess file inside my wordpress folder :

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myblogsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myblogsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: How does this block others from accessing my website
@Aftab

Answer (score 2):

You can create a local server with the installing linux and then you can add your project to that server so that all your team member which are connected with same network are can view the site.

When you install Apache or IIS or any other web server application (in your case WAMP), your computer acts as a web server. Check your Local Network Address. Something like 192.168.xxx.xxx.Suppose you are running a WP site on your localhost as `http://localhost/wordpress` then everyone connected to your network can access your site using `http://192.168.xxx.xxx/wordpress`

Comment: I already have server installed wamp64. and I have added my project there. That is why I am getting my website in the link http://localhost/wordpressfoldername OR http://myipaddress/wordpressfoldername

Why linux?

Comment: You are getting that localhost error because you haven't updated your siteurl in wp-admin/Settings/General. Update those two urls to your new localhost ip address, then the site should resolve properly.

Comment: @Tarun modi - by Check your Local Network Address - you mean go to cmd prompt and check ipconfig(ipv4 address?) or is something different

Comment: yes ipv4 address

Comment: I am giving that only(http://ipv4/mywordpressfoldername) from other machines am getting the below error.
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /myblogsite on this server.
Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at 10.21.76.46 Port 80

Comment: Please check the permission of the folder

Comment: also turn on the network sharing

Comment: Can you pls let me know how to do the above two things. I have shared the wamp64 folder, www folder and my wordpress folder with everyone How does I turn on network sharing
@Tarunmodi

Comment: Hi pls check to type the IP address in directly in browser

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a Virtual Host and setup WP there.

And you can ask member of your company to add the virtual host name, in their vhost file.

And anyone within your company connected to same network can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the web server like it is being set in all the hosting providers. Use some out of use machine for that, don't use your personal one.

Once you got a machine set up, ask you IT guy to give you an IP address for that machine and configure internal DNS address that maps to it. To that machine only you (maybe) and your IT should have root access.

Now you just install wordpress like you would have done in any other scenario, just use your local DNS address as the address for the site